# Is it necessary to apply spaced repetition when reading research papers?

Tags: publications, research-process, literature-review

I'm an undergraduate who is going to be a Ph.D candidate this fall. After reading papers extensively for writing the literature review, I realize details in some papers, though I totally understand them at the moment I read them, are almost forgotten when I try to cite these papers.

I wonder what's your habit to keep track of the papers you've read (for long-term retrieval).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remember something long term, spaced repetition is a good way to remember it.

I interact with hundreds of papers per year.  Trying to remember them all is futile.  You should prioritize.

Answer (score 2):

There are various methods to keep track of your readings; a spaced repetition is not necessarily indispensable.

My preferred approach is: to annotate, to collect excerpts, and to tag these excerpts so that one can find them again when one searches by keywords.

Citation managers such as *[Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/)* offer these functions.

I personally use a digital 'Zettelkasten' (*[TiddlyWiki](https://tiddlywiki.com/)*) for this purpose.

Both *Zotero* and *TiddlyWiki* are open-source and free.

Answer (score 0):

Statements that are not excessively technical can be written in the appropriate Wikipedia article, while citing the article as a source. To some extent, Wikipedia can thus be used as a shared guide to the literature.

Of course, you need another solution for the technical details and personal annotations: see the other answers.